# Implementing Java serialization independent encoding

Tags: serialization, xstream, asn.1, protocol-buffers

I want to use several encodings in the presentation layer to encode a object/structure in the application layeri independenty from encoding scheme (such as binary, XML, etc) and programming language (Java, Javascript, PHP, C).

An example would be to transfer an object from a producer to a consumer in a byte stream. The Java client would encode it using something like this:

```
Object var = new Dog(); 
output.writeObject(var);
```

The server would share the Dog class definitions and could regenerate the object doing something like this:

```
Object var = input.readObject(); 
assertTrue(var instanceof Dog); // passes
```

It is important to note that producer and consumer would not share the type of var, and, therefore, the consumer would not need the type to decode var. They only would share data type definitions, if ever:

```
public interface Pojo {}
public class Dog implements Pojo { int i; String s; } // Generated by framework from a spec
```

What I found:

1. Java Serialization: It is language dependent. Cannot be used with for example javascript.
2. Protobuf library: It is limited to a specific binary format. It is not possible to support additional binary formats. Need name of class ("class" of message).
3. XStream, Simple, etc. They are rather limited to text/XML and require name of the class.
4. ASN.1: The standards are there and could be used with OBJECT IDENTIFIER and type definitions but they lack on documentation and tutorials.

I prefer 4th option because, among others, it is a standard. Is there any active project that support such requirements (specially something based on ASN.1)? Any usage example? Does the project include codecs (DER, BER, XER, etc.) that can be selected at runtime?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can find several open source and commercial implementation of tools for ASN.1. These usually include:

- a compiler for the schema, which will generate code in your desired programming language
- a runtime library which is used together with the generated code for encoding and decoding

ASN.1 is mainly used with the standardized communication protocols for telecom industry, so the commercial tools have very good support for the ASN.1 standard and various encoding rules.

Here are some starter tutorials and even free e-books:

http://www.oss.com/asn1/resources/asn1-made-simple/introduction.html

http://www.oss.com/asn1/resources/reference/asn1-reference-card.html

http://www.oss.com/asn1/resources/books-whitepapers-pubs/asn1-books.html

I know that the OSS ASN.1 commercial tools (http://www.oss.com/asn1/products/asn1-products.html) will support switching the encoding rules at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

To add to bosonix's answer, there's also Objective System's tools at http://www.obj-sys.com/. The documentation from both OSS and Objective Systems includes many example uses.

ASN.1 is pretty much perfect for what you're looking for. I know of no other serialisation system that does this quite so thoroughly.

As well as a whole array of different binary encodings (ranging from the comprehensively tagged BER all the way down to the very packed-together PER), it does XML and now also JSON encodings too. These are well standardised by the ITU, so it is in theory fully inter operable between tool vendors, programming languages, OSes, etc.

There are other significant benefits to ASN.1. The schema language lets you define constraints on the value of message fields, or the sizes of arrays. These then get checked for you by the generated code. This is far more complete than many other serialisations. For instance, Google Protocol Buffers doesn't let you do this, meaning that you have to check the range of message fields (where applicable) in hand written code. That's tedious, error prone, and hard to maintain.

The only other ones that do this are XSD and JSON schemas. However with those you're at the mercy of the varying quality of tools used to turn those into source code - I've not yet seen any decent ones for JSON schemas. I'm not aware of whether or not Microsoft's xsd.exe honours such constraints either.